# or operator with jquery not working how i'd expect..?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement, operators

```
$('input[TYPE="SUBMIT"]').click(function(){
    if ($('input[TYPE="TEXT"').val().length===0 || $('textarea').val().length===0)
    {
        console.log($('input[TYPE="TEXT"').val().length);
        console.log($('textarea').val().length);
        return false;
    }
});
```

chrome highlights my if statement.  I really don't see what's wrong here.  I suppose I could add a class to both fields, but I don't really need that for my layout.  Am I writing this incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have `'input[TYPE="TEXT"'` with a missing `]` in quite a few places, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

What I've immediately noticed is that

`$('input[TYPE="TEXT"')`

should be

`$('input[TYPE="TEXT"]')`

Note, however, that making a selection like this will only check the length of the **first** textbox/textarea it finds, not each of them.

What you'd need in that case would be something like this:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function()
{
    var ok = true;
    $("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function() {
        ok &= ok && $(this).val().length > 0;
    });
    alert(ok ? 'All OK' : 'Not OK :(');
});
```

Even better would be giving the submit button a proper ID and the input elements some other attribute, so you don't accidentally include other controls in the validation.

```
<input type="text" validate="true" />

$("*[validate='true']").each(function() {
    ok &= ok && $(this).val().length > 0;
});
```

Comment: @ionfish: Please see my edit, because if I'm correct and you're trying to do validation, you have to approach it differently anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
($('input[TYPE=TEXT]').val().length == 0 || $('textarea').val().length == 0)
```

Comment: Although you've posted a correction, it would have been more helpful if there was at least a brief explanation as to what was wrong.

Comment: You've removed the mandatory quotation marks from around the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[TYPE="TEXT"/*]*/')`

You forgot the `]`

I recommend you use the `:text` pseudo selector instead ;)

`$("input:text");`

[`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

Comment: `:text` prevents `querySelectorAll` from being used. :o( Proprietary selectors... grrrr!

Comment: @patrick_dw but it's the jQuery way! Either way if you actually cared about speed you would give these inputs a useful class name.

Comment: I wonder how much difference using a class name instead would make. Does jQuery optimize for class-only selectors by sending to `getElementsByClassName` like they do (I think) for ID selectors? I assumed it would go to `qsa` either way.

Comment: `class` being an attribute just as `type` is, I have assumed that the performance isn't very different, and in fact may be a little slower with `class` since multiple classes are supported. But it would be implementation specific, and I haven't done any testing, so it's all just assumptions. Either way, I always try to use `qsa` supported selectors.